# Защита от ddos проверка на человека

Tags: ubuntu, apache, nginx, ddos, ufw

На сайте http://www.dalaran-wow.com реализована некоторая система от клаудфлаер которая якобы защищает от ддос атак.

Есть идея сделать аналогичную защиту для своего сайта которая новому посетителю показывала бы капчу, и при успешном прохождении открывала доступ к сайту добавляя его ip адрес в список разрешенных в ufw firewall.

Ps недавно подвергся легкой атаке с тайм аут запросами на апач, хотелось бы подстраховаться на будущее. Для сайта это не критично иметь капчу или некий предзагрузочный модуль на входе. Суть в том чтобы оградить от не человека (маленького ботнета) 80 порт, создать некую прослойку на внешнем сервере которая бы проверяла на бот/не бот и посылала соответсвующий запрос. Есть ли готовые решения такого плана?

Сервер ubuntu 16(к сожалению).

Comment: а Вы думаете, что задедосить через каптчу не получится? ещё как. Нормальный ддос-протектор обычно живет на отдельном сервере (серверах) и проксирует траффик.

Comment: Что то в этом духе и хотел. Просто я в этом новичек. Есть ли ссылки на решения? Бюджет можно сказать нулевой максимум на vds. А через капчу я хотел открывать доступ к сайту, а сама капча была бы преградой к массовому спаму с разных ip , капчу можно было бы разместить на платном хостинге например.